# Getting the width of all child components contained in an NgTemplate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I've got this markup in the template. I can iterate through its component using `get` but it's not returning an object which allows me to dig deep enough in the HTML attributes.

```
<ng-template #container></ng-template>
```

I dynamically add components to this `container` above.

My component code

```
@ViewChild("container", { read: ViewContainerRef }) appAsideContainer: ViewContainerRef;


for (var x = 0; x < this.appAsideContainer.length; x++) {
    let c: ViewRef = this.appAsideContainer.get(x);
    console.log(c);
}
```

`c` doesn't give me access to either `element` or `nativeElement` so I could get `offsetWidth`

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by using `rootNodes` property after casting to `EmbeddedViewRef`:

```
for (var x = 0; x < this.appAsideContainer.length; x++) {
  const viewRef = this.appAsideContainer.get(x) as EmbeddedViewRef<any>;
  const rootNode = viewRef.rootNodes[0];
  console.log(rootNode);
}
```